# ALTER APPEND on 40 Billion Row Table times out - strategies to get around?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, scaling

As the title states, I have a table in Redshift with nearly 40 Billion rows. I cannot execute an ALTER APPEND as it times out.

What are some patterns and strategies for getting around this?
Thanks.

Comment: Mechanical turk? :)

Comment: @mayersdesign heh

Comment: https://www.quora.com/I-have-a-table-that-has-1-3-billion-sales-rows-and-most-of-the-columns-are-indexed-It-still-takes-a-long-time-for-me-to-run-a-procedure-or-a-view-even-with-conditions-How-do-I-solve-the-issue is an interesting read,m but your problem beyond me. Good luck! I have to ask.... 40b rows of "what"? Hashes? ;)

Comment: The data is lists of mailing recipients.

Comment: You are moving 40B rows or appending to an existing table with that many? Table has had a recent VACUUM? Are there competing INSERT or UPDATE queries running?

Comment: Appending to an existing table with no data. Table hasn't had a recent vacuum. No competing queries.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing an incremental select/insert, using client id column which existed from 2 to 2495, breaking it up by 25 (`between 0 and 25` for first query). I wrote a python script to generate all the SQL statements, then executed the output of the script.

It took a while but it worked.